# Detecting surface markings on scattered electron microscope images

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection

I am trying to create regions of interest of the little dot markers on the surface. I have tried a number of filtering and detection techniques to no avail. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

I am trying to determine the position and size of markings on a sample for tensile testing.

[image]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iWz945p7CcKTvevJHBNImTYIQ7ZzieeP/view?usp=sharing

link to the high-quality image file as it is like 50 mb

currently this is what i have

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

def filter_sem_image(image_path):
    
    image = cv2.imread(image_path, 0)  # Read the image as grayscale
    
    denoised_image = cv2.medianBlur(image, 3)


    # Enhance contrast using histogram equalization
    equalized_image = cv2.equalizeHist(denoised_image)

    # Apply adaptive thresholding to segment the dots
    _, thresholded_image = cv2.threshold(equalized_image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    # Find contours in the thresholded image
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresholded_image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # Filter the contours based on size and shape
    filtered_contours = []
    for contour in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
        perimeter = cv2.arcLength(contour, True)
        circularity = 4 * np.pi * area / (perimeter ** 2)

        # Exclude larger cracks and ensure circularity of the dots
        if area < 1000 and circularity > 0.7:
            filtered_contours.append(contour)

    # Draw the filtered contours on a blank image
    filtered_image = np.zeros_like(image)
    cv2.drawContours(filtered_image, filtered_contours, -1, (255), thickness=cv2.FILLED)

    return filtered_image


sem_image_path = "sem_image.jpg"
filtered_image = filter_sem_image(sem_image_path)


cv2.imshow("Filtered SEM Image", filtered_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: The google drive link requires us to request permission. You can change it so that "anyone with the link can `view`"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: on a low level, those things are bright outlines with sharp edges. you could manually code detection for that. or you could grab some object detection network or convolutional network and train it to respond to those things.